# How to grow text from bottom to top in a boostrap card

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am using a *Bootstrap-4* card in my web page.

I want the text in `card-body` to grow from bottom to top.

```
 <div class="col-xl-3 col-sm-6 mb-3">
    <div class="card text-white color4 o-hidden h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="mr-5"><span class="float-left" 
        style="min-width:280px;font-size:17px;">Tool</span> 
        </div>
            <p>Contents i want this text to grow from bottom 
             to top.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you mean `grow`? Text is already 25 years old....

Comment: Grow relative to what? .. are there adjacent elements?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean. I guess you want to grow your text?
You can use:

```
p {
font-size: 60px;
}
```

or even better

```
your-div-name p {
font-size: 60px;
}
```